# Showing that the winding number is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory, winding-number

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway I am stuck at. Here $n($$\gamma$ $,$ $w$) is the winding number and $(6.2)$ is like below.

[image]

I need to prove that $h$ is continuous using only the definition of winding number, not Cauchy Theorem. In fact I have to use the result of the exercise 9 to prove the Cauchy Theorem. So, I have to use some $\delta$ $-$ $\epsilon$ argument. But, I can't find a way to do so. Could anyone help me how to solve the exercise 9?

The definition of winding number is like below.
[image]

Comment: For $\gamma_t$ a uniformly continuous family of finite length smooth curves then $F(t) = \int_{\gamma_t} \frac{dz}{z}$ is discontinuous at $t = t_0$ implies $\gamma_{t_0}$ passes through $z = 0$ (proof : $\frac{1}{z}$ is continuous away from $z=0$ !). In particular $\gamma_{t_0-\epsilon}$ and $\gamma_{t_0+\epsilon}$ are not homotopically equivalent in $\mathbb{C}^*$

Comment: How does Conway define the winding number ?

Comment: @Gribouillis I included that in my question.

Comment: Do you understand my comment ? $\int_{\gamma_t} h(z)dz$ *is continuous in $t$ whenever $h$ is continuous*. Also you didn't define $G$ which obviously must not contain $z=a$.

Comment: The question is maked as duplicate, but the answer in the other thread has a broken link!